# Outlook calendar authentication with ADFS and a default Windows Auth zone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, adfs

We configured a Sharepoint portal with two zones. One (default) with windows authentication because of the search crawler, and another with and ADFS provider.

In the browser (using the ADFS zone) everything works.

Now the problem. We can sync a calendar with outlook, and it opens, but when we try to edit something (or when it tries to sync), outlook asks for authentication but on the default (windows auth) zone that only has the user for the crawler with permissions.

Does anybody know why this appends? And any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Outlook tries to authenticate in the first zone he can find.

An the order of the first zones is:

Intranet
Default
...

So essentially we change the ADFS zone to the intranet zone and it worked.